# Making Two API calls in react using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am making an app where I send and receive data from one API. Once I get this data I want to make another call to the some other API sending this data to this second API and receiving data from this second API.

```
export const uploadImage = (data) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE });
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://3.14.136.182:80/predict',
        data: data,
        "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        timeout: 20000
    })
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
        data = response.data;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '3.14.136.182:8005/finalResult',
            data: data,
            "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            timeout: 20000
        })
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS, payload: response.data});
            console.log("Mehmood",response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE });
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE });
    })


}
```

Comment: ... and the problem is...?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking so that your answer would be more likely to be answered than downvoted.

Comment: please specify what your problem is, if there are error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing at one `return` statement in you first then block. (before axios). Also you are dispatching success two times.